# Why is Babel importing already supported polyfill?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm using `rollup js` and Babel to transpile my javascript but why is babel adding a `polyfill` for "promises"? when chrome is supporting promises from version 33. I'm targeting `chrome version > 61`

**Debug mode:**

Added following `core-js polyfill: es.promise { "chrome":"62" }`

**rollup.config.js**

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";

export default [
    {
        input: "src/main.js",
        output: {
            file: "./dist/bundle-modern.js",
            format: "iife",
            name: "bundle"
        },
        plugins: [
            babel({
                exclude: "node_modules/**",
                presets: [
                    [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        {
                            targets: {
                                browsers: ["Chrome > 61"]
                            },
                            useBuiltIns: "usage",
                            corejs: 3,
                            debug: true
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs()
        ]
    }
];
```

**main.js**

```
function checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response;
    } else {
        var error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json();
}

fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("request succeeded with JSON response", data.results);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("request failed", error);
    });
```

Comment: What exactly was the polyfill code that was added? Notice that Chrome 62 for example doesn't support [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: @Bergi [here](https://codepen.io/Lukuh/pen/pozqRvV?editors=0010) is a codepen with the polyfill code that is added

Comment: OK, that's weird indeed.

Comment: same problem, babel add es.string.replace while browserlist Chrome > 60